# Nilpotent Matrices Questions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotent-groups

[Nilpotent Matrix Question Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9ewJ.png)

I was wondering if anyone could help with the latter parts of the question (b & c).
I have concluded from part A that Matrix "A" is Nilpotent as det(A)=0 and tr(A)=0, and that Matrix "B" is not Nilpotent as det(B) does not equal 0 and tr(B)=0. However, I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: Now start evaluating $A^2, A^3, A^4, ...$ until you reach the zero matrix. It won't be long.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I have already done this and concluded information from this for question A. I was wondering if you had any input on part B) and C)

Comment: for part c) show that  $x,D x,D x^2,\text{...},D x^{k-1}$  are linearly independent

Comment: Thanks for your input! How would I go about this seeing as I don't have any numerical values?

Comment: write a linear combination and apply $D$ successively

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit baffled. What linear combination am I creating and how would I apply D successively?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$D^k=0$ but  $D^{k-1}\neq 0$. Therefore there exists a vector  $x$  such that
$$ D^{k-1}x\neq 0$$

Show $x,D x,D^2x,\text{...},D^{k-1}x$ are linearly independent.
To do this consider a linear combination and set it equal to zero then show the coefficients must all be zero as follows

$$a_0x+a_1D x+a_2D^2x+\text{...}+a_{k-1}D^{k-1}x=0$$

Apply $D$ to both sides of this equation $(k-1)$ times

you should get

$$a_0D^{k-1}x=0$$

this shows $a_0=0$

continue ...

Comment: Wow, thank you soo much for taking time to help me. Very much appreciated. I'm definitely getting so much closer to grasping this concept.